# Adding text to Data Grid View Horizontal Scroll Bar

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I am trying to put the file name on my data grid view horizontal scroll Bar.
After looking at [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I learned that there is a `Text` Property for Horizontal Scroll Bar but when
I looked in `dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<HScrollBar>().First()` there is no `Text` variable. I was wondering if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Overlay it with a label? and change the text on the label?

Comment: the problem is the Data Grid View is always moving and I did not want to keep moving the label.

Comment: also transparent background does not work since the label chooses a color when it first start the program and when you hover over the scroll bar the color of the scroll bar changes.